# Exporting joined attribute table features gives wrong number of records using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, attribute-joins, dissolve

I work in ArcMap 10.8.1.
I have a feature class of ~40k records of road segments. I dissolved the segments using a field containing numbername of the roads. This created a feature class of ~10k records (actual roads). Then I joined tables from the original 40k to the new dissolved one - so I could keep the attributes that were lost during the dissolve process. The joining was a success. In the attr table I can see all the fields.

Now when I try to export the features into a new gdb file, so I can keep the joined data, it says "exporting 0/10 000 records" then it proceeds to "exporting 10 000 / 10 000 records" and should be done...BUT! it continues to "exporting 40 000 / 10 000 records" and the resulting feature class has 40 000 records. I even tried manually selecting the 10k records and exporting them. Still the same result.

I know there are multiple records from the original feature class joining into to the dissolved feature class but I don't care which one is joined, the field values are the same.

What's happening?

The attribute table shows only the dissolved number of records but when exporting it exports 40k records.

Comment: Have you selected "Keep only matching records"?

Comment: Yes I have, still the same result. There are more matching results as in 3 records from the original match 1 from the dissolved. - which is logical because they got dissolved from 40k to 10k records

Comment: It's not likely that all your roads are not actually connected, but to be sure you might select all your records (prior to the join) and see if they explode to produce the original records.  Alternately you could use the multipart to singlepart.  If they are separate you might have to run a "clean"/intersect to make sure they are connected.

Comment: They exploded into ~17k records (not the original number). How does this help me? I need to connect the attributes to the records and keep them.